# Cordova WebView rendering failure on overflow

Tags: html, css, windows, cordova, webview

I have got some display problems with my cordova app in Windows 10.
The body is positions absolute to fix the size of the apps content. Inside I have got a  styles to show overflow as scrolling content. This content is created in runtime. It is some form with kind of dropdown lists.

All is working fine. But if the form exceeds some critical length, clicking on items in the form results moving upward the complete UI of my app and showing some grey background. I tried to debug using Visual Studio  but I can not find any wrong CSS nor an open tag. When debugging, any change in overflow definition results in correct display of the app UI - not depending on the value.

Moving up the UI seems to be dependend on form length and the position of the object relative in form. Element on top of the form have no influence. Elements at the bottom move the complete UI out of sight.

Do you have any suggestions or ideas, what I should look for? Or ist the some known issue concerning overflow rendering?

Best regards,
TGJahn

---

edit 2018-02-19
Screenshots of the app

[App interface as it should be. right before selecting the option "Astungswunden oder -fäulen"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGY0Y.png)

[Right after selecting the option.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMxDz.png)

Body and page wrapper are defined as

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
height:auto;
overflow:hidden;
```

Since the app is quite complex I am trying to isolate the essential parts of the code....

Comment: Please share your code, some screenshot etc..

Comment: Added screenshots. Code will follow

Comment: And give me your html code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, long research short result: I had some CSS trick (I had found on web some time ago and it worked well for all use cases before) for styled checkboxes. (making these checkboxes invisible and doing some nice display using labels).
Those checkboxes were placed below by the Webview and resulted in the described behaviour. Using Visual Studio debugging tools I could not highlight them. I have extracted the whole generated html code and placed it into some extra file, so I could use Chrome's developer tools. That way I recognized the invisible boxes and changed my css along.